# Added column does not sort as the last column

Tags: cassandra

I just upgraded from Cassandra 1.1.7 to 1.2.3 and im now seeing a lot of the following error in my output.log, cant find much on the web about it:

ERROR 11:56:01,317 Exception in thread Thread[ReadStage:7236,5,main]
java.lang.AssertionError: Added column does not sort as the last column
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ArrayBackedSortedColumns.addColumn(ArrayBackedSortedColumns.java:131)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractColumnContainer.addColumn(AbstractColumnContainer.java:109)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.AbstractColumnContainer.addColumn(AbstractColumnContainer.java:104)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.SliceQueryFilter.collectReducedColumns(SliceQueryFilter.java:171)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateColumns(QueryFilter.java:136)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.filter.QueryFilter.collateOnDiskAtom(QueryFilter.java:84)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.collectAllData(CollationController.java:294)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.CollationController.getTopLevelColumns(CollationController.java:65)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getTopLevelColumns(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1363)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1220)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.ColumnFamilyStore.getColumnFamily(ColumnFamilyStore.java:1132)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.Table.getRow(Table.java:348)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.SliceFromReadCommand.getRow(SliceFromReadCommand.java:70)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$LocalReadRunnable.runMayThrow(StorageProxy.java:1052)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageProxy$DroppableRunnable.run(StorageProxy.java:1578)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

I dont know Java and im struggling to identify exactly which query is causing this, is there a way to trace this back to a specific query?

Any help appreciated.

Sam

Answer (score 1):

You could enable probabilistic tracing (http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/advanced-request-tracing-in-cassandra-1-2) and check for activity entries that match this exception.  Unfortunately you would need the patch from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-5447 to include the exception.

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, I eventually found I had some data corruption on the keys of these CF's which looks to have been causing the issue.